# Orthogonal similarity of block real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices, matrix-analysis

Can a block real symmetric matrix whose sum of diagonal blocks is an identity matrix
$$\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    H^{T}_{1}H_{1} & H^{T}_{2}H_{2} & \cdots & H^{T}_{1}H_{n+1} \\
    H^{T}_{1}H_{2} & H^{T}_{2}H_{2} & \cdots & H^{T}_{2}H_{n+1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots &   & \vdots \\
    H^{T}_{1}H_{n+1} & H^{T}_{2}H_{n+1} & \cdots & H^{T}_{n+1}H_{n+1} \\
  \end{array}
\right]~\left(H^{T}_{1}H_{1}+\cdots+H^{T}_{n+1}H_{n+1}=I_{N}\right)$$
be orthogonally similar to a block diagonal matrix whose sum of diagonal blocks is also an identity matrix
$$\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    \tilde{H}^{T}_{1}\tilde{H}_{1} &   &   &   \\
      & \tilde{H}^{T}_{2}\tilde{H}_{2} &   &   \\
      &   & \ddots &   \\
      &   &   & \tilde{H}^{T}_{n+1}\tilde{H}_{n+1} \\
  \end{array}
\right]~\left(\tilde{H}^{T}_{1}\tilde{H}_{1}+\cdots+\tilde{H}^{T}_{n+1}\tilde{H}_{n+1}=I_{N}\right)$$

Comment: For N=1, it is obvious.

Comment: If this occurs, then it must hold that $\sum_i \operatorname{rank}(\tilde H_i) \leq N$

Comment: The phrasing of your question is confusing. Are you asking if there exists at least one set of $H_i$ such that this occurs (for a given $n,N$), or are you asking whether this occurs for **all** such matrices $H_i$?

Comment: If
$$H_{i}=\mathrm{C}_{i}U_{1},~i=1,\cdots,n+1,$$
where $\mathrm{C}_{1},\cdots,\mathrm{C}_{n+1} \in M_{N(n+1)}(\mathbb{R})$ are diagonal matrices with $\mathrm{C}_{1}^{2}+\cdots+\mathrm{C}_{n+1}^{2}=I_{N(n+1)}$,
$U_{1}=\left[
         \begin{array}{cccc}
           u_{1} & u_{2} & \cdots & u_{N} \\
         \end{array}
       \right]$,
$u_{1},\cdots,u_{N} \in \mathbb{R}^{N(n+1)}$ are orthonormal vectors,
is there exists at least one set of $\tilde{H}_{i}$ such that this occurs? 
@Ben Grossmann